# Storm-crawler seed injection fails on AWS node

Tags: stormcrawler

I'm using storm-crawler 1.15 on a AWS instance (ES 7.3.0, Storm 1.2.3)
The seed injection (ESSeedInjector) fails and I can't figure out why. Basically every single url that is passed to the "enqueue" bolt get failed.

Here is an exerpt of the apache worker log:

```
...
2019-11-13 09:38:18.937 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 4 TUPLE: source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquaplex.pvi.com/, , DISCOVERED]
2019-11-13 09:38:18.937 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquaplex.pvi.com/, discoveryDate: 2019-11-13T09:38:18.937Z
, DISCOVERED] TASK: 4 DELTA: -1
2019-11-13 09:38:18.937 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 4 TUPLE: source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquaponics.com/aquaponic-systems/com\
mercial-systems/, , DISCOVERED]
2019-11-13 09:38:18.937 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquaponics.com/aquaponic-systems/commercial-systems/, disc\
overyDate: 2019-11-13T09:38:18.937Z
, DISCOVERED] TASK: 4 DELTA: -1
2019-11-13 09:38:18.937 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 4 TUPLE: source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquarium-fish.kamihata.net/guppy/, ,\
 DISCOVERED]
2019-11-13 09:38:18.935 c.d.s.e.p.StatusUpdaterBolt I/O dispatcher 2 [ERROR] Exception with bulk 1 - failing the whole lot
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Unable to parse response body
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1707) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient$1.onFailure(RestHighLevelClient.java:1621) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onDefinitiveFailure(RestClient.java:564) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:310) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:294) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://node-1], URI [/_bulk?timeout=1m], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /_bulk was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>

        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:253) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.access$900(RestClient.java:95) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:298) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        ... 16 more
2019-11-13 09:38:18.938 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquarium-fish.kamihata.net/guppy/, discoveryDate: 2019-11-\
13T09:38:18.937Z
, DISCOVERED] TASK: 4 DELTA: -1
2019-11-13 09:38:18.938 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 4 TUPLE: source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquarius-spectrum.com/pdf/Aquarius-S\
pectrum-PPT.pdf, , DISCOVERED]
2019-11-13 09:38:18.938 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquarius-spectrum.com/pdf/Aquarius-Spectrum-PPT.pdf, disco\
veryDate: 2019-11-13T09:38:18.938Z
, DISCOVERED] TASK: 4 DELTA: -1
2019-11-13 09:38:18.938 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-16-enqueue-executor[4 4] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 4 TUPLE: source: filter:5, stream: status, id: {}, [http://aquaservinc.com/contact-us/, , DISCO\
...
```

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the port of the ES server correctly? It looks like you are hitting a normal HTTP server, which of course doesn't know anything about _bulk.

See [example ES conf](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/es-conf.yaml). It should pick the default port if unspecified so setting just the host should be fine.

Comment: Hi Julien, yes, all fully specified (with node-1 in our /etc/hosts on the private ip of the node)
  ```es.indexer.addresses: "http://node-1:9200"
  es.metrics.addresses: "http://node-1:9200"
  es.status.addresses: "http://node-1:9200"```

Comment: and http://pub_ip:9200 gives:
```name "node-1"
cluster_name "ESPatentCluster"
cluster_uuid "ySHUU80xRyOdrzhO93AKEQ"
version 
number "7.3.0"
build_flavor "default"
build_type "tar"
build_hash "de777fa"
build_date "2019-07-24T18:30:11.767338Z"
build_snapshot false
lucene_version "8.1.0"
minimum_wire_compatibility_version "6.8.0"
minimum_index_compatibility_version "6.0.0-beta1"
tagline "You Know, for Search"```

Comment: could you please try to use the private ip directly in the config?

Comment: Hi Julien,
With SC 1.14 and ES 7.0.0 things are OK, it injects properly.
But I will give it a go and let you know